# Android Emulator unbearably slow

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an AMD processor, so I am unable to download the Intel X86 Emulator Accelerator. My computer is very capable of running this at a high setting, but i find it takes about 5 minutes for the actual emulator to boot, and the upload speed when running the new additions to the app take about 3 minutes.

Is there an equivalent for an AMD accelerator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options for that :

1- As what @guy gc said, you can try Genymotion.

2- Use Android Studio 2.0 emulator, it's the new generation for Android Studio, and faster more then the older one.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/)? It's more stable and faster the the stock emulator

Comment: Ah no I have not tried that yet, but I surely will now! Thanks!